# onNotificationAPN not called

Tags: ios, cordova

When I implement *push-notification* in *iOS* using *phonegap 2.3.0*,
I get the token Handler message, but when sending message from server I don't get the message alert.

The main problem is that *onNotificatinAPN* function is not called.

I am using *phonegap 2.3.0* version.

```
window.plugins.pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {
    "badge": "true",
    "sound": "true",
    "alert": "true",
    "ecb": "onNotificationAPN"
});
onNotificationAPN: function(e) {
    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    if (e.alert) {
        navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
    }
    if (e.badge) {
        console.log("Set badge on  " + pushNotification);
        pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(this.successHandler, e.badge);
    }
    if (e.sound) {
        var snd = new Media(e.sound);
        snd.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you make sure message was send to device. Sometime it can error from server side.

Comment: at every time when i run the app i get device token number.

Answer (score 2):

onNotificationAPN must be scope in window: window.onNotificationAPN = function(message){};

Answer (score 0):

your device id is not inside `onNotificationAPN()`

It's inside `tokenHandler()` function

```
function tokenHandler(result) {
    console.log('device token = ' + result);
}
```

Comment: i declared device token inside onNotificationAPN(), but result not getting.